# How can I correctly assign a pointer to a call back function?

Tags: c, pointers, keil

I try to call a function in a IRQ with C, with the next code I get it.

```
static void (*functionPulsacion)();

void eint2_init(void *funcPulsacion){
    functionPulsacion = funcPulsacion;
}
```

But when I compile in Keil the IDE show me the next message:

> Button2.c(38): warning:  #513-D: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "void (*)()"

What is the good way for do this?.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The parameter of `eint2_init` should be of the correct function pointer type, not just a `void*`

Comment: The assignment is not incorrect. It is a bit of a pedantic warning. But in this case, I would say it's wise to change the function definition to `void eint2_init(void (*funcPulsacion)(void)){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same syntax for the parameter variable as for the static one.

```c
static void (*functionPulsacion)(void);

void eint2_init(void (*funcPulsacion)(void)) {
    functionPulsacion = funcPulsacion;
}
```

Typedefs make function pointers a lot more readable, though.

```c
typedef void (*PulsacionFunc)(void);

static PulsacionFunc pulsacion_func;

void eint2_init(PulsacionFunc a_pulsacion_func) {
   pulsacion_func = a_pulsacion_func;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the type of `funcPulsacion` matches that of `functionPulsacion`, like so:

```
static void (*functionPulsacion)(void);

void eint2_init(void (*funcPulsacion)(void)) {
    functionPulsacion = funcPulsacion;
}
```

It helps to use `typedef` to define the function pointer type so it can be reused:

```
typedef void (*functionPulsacion_type)(void);

static void functionPulsacion_type functionPulsacion;

void eint2_init(functionPulsacion_type funcPulsacion) {
    functionPulsacion = funcPulsacion;
}
```

Comment: For completeness it's probably best to also show the solution without the typedef.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of a pointer to a variadic function that returns `void`.

```c
static void (*functionPulsacion)();
```

The argument to this function, however, is `void *`

```c
void eint2_init(void *funcPulsacion){
    functionPulsacion = funcPulsacion;
}
```

Funny thing is, with any data pointer, you *could* assign a `void *` without any issues

```c
void foo(void *vp)
{
    int *ip = vp;
}

void bar(void *vp)
{
    char *cp = vp;
}
```

but according to the standard, *not* to a function pointer

```c
void nope(void *vp)
{
    void (*fp)() = vp; // this might be a problem!
}
```

Any data pointer can be cast to a `void *` and back again, without even a warning.
But that is *data* pointers; not function pointers. I belive that POSIX says that
you can assign between `void *` and function pointers, but the C standard does not.

You can cast between function pointers, though.

Of course, that is dangerous, because once you call the function it doesn't care what
type you think it has; it will do its thing according to what type it knows it has.
So, it is best just to use the right pointer type here.

```c
void yeah(void (*arg)())
{
    void (*fp)() = arg;
}
```